# Set multiple values in a char array at once in C (reimplementing strcpy)

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

How to copy information word by word instead of byte by byte like Apple (or any other enterprice's C library) does? ([Their `memcpy` for reference](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1699.24.8/libsyscall/wrappers/memcpy.c.auto.html), where they used a structure "word" to copy information of a set size. [Their `strcpy`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-3789.21.4/libsyscall/wrappers/string/strcpy.c.auto.html) just calls `memcpy`)

When I do something like this (`mystrcpy` copies byte by byte):

```
char *src = "Hi";
char *dst = malloc(3); // or 99, just so the focus is method instead
mystrcpy(dst, src);    // of safety or this very specific case
```

The dst would be as: `? ? ?` -> `'H' ? ?` -> `'H' 'i' ?` -> `'H' 'i' 0`
To clarify the question, what would be the simpliest code for `mystrcpy` that makes dst go directly from `? ? ?` to `'H' 'i' 0` in one step?
I ask because I am having a very difficult time understanding Apple's source code and Googling yields nothing of the like. If someone could simplify and explain Apple's code it'd be appreciated.

Update to include the current `mystrcpy`:

```
char    *mystrcpy(char *dst, const char *src)
{
    char    *tmp;

    tmp = dst;
    while (*src)
        *tmp++ = *src++;
    *tmp = 0;
    return (dst);
}
```

Comment: Can you post your mystrcpy?

Comment: In one step would, in my opinion and understanding, imply also writing to the byte behind dst (or maybe before); which is too dangerous.

Comment: Well, unless your system has word size of 3, you don't have any other option here ... you will find the "word-size memcpy" implementations copy chunks of 2, 4, or 8 , but they still have to have extra code to deal with these odd ends

Comment: You can't. As you've written your example you explicitly can't do it because `strcpy` is not allowed to touch memory outside of the exact bytes it needs to and there are no 3 byte registers on any machine I'm aware of.

Comment: Many `memcpy` implementations copy longer chunks of memory at once, for example it could copy 64 bits (8 bytes) at a time. However, for a *string* copy it's not really possible, unless you know where the terminator is from the beginning (which means a byte-wise operation to find it).

Comment: @M.M That was only for example; could you please explain, for example, how it works with a size 30 string with word size 8?

Comment: It **doesn't** work in standard C because you're not allowed to alias a `char` array with an incompatible type. A standard library can do it because it knows the implementation and could for example rely on that specific implementation to allow aliasing the `char` array as e.g. `int`, given some specific circumstances.

Comment: I think the Apple source code is naive, it will force a traversal of the string twice and the compiler can't optimize that. The `strlen` call is the process-heavy one with all the branches, to write a loop that both checks for null termination and does a copy will likely take about as much time as the call to `strlen` in itself. And then of course such code could be further optimized by writing chunks of aligned data.

Comment: So you think you can outperform your standard library implementation by asking a question on stackoverflow. Why, that's totally possible. The authors of your standard library surely haven't heard about stackoverflow yet. A bunch of newbies.

Comment: @n.m. ? anything wrong with trying to understand how things work?

Comment: Sorry misread your question. It is difficult to write a good memcpy implementation, but it's rarely needed because compilers are very good at inlining these functions nowadays. So the library function end up being almost never called in optimised code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fully optimized implementations that implement `strcpy()` by copying register-sized chunks as much as possible are usually convoluted and non-portable. In particular, they tend to be written in assembly language for a given platform. They use a single-pass design, without resorting to `strlen()`.

Below I am showing semi-portable C code that should work on all little-endian 64-bit platforms, such as x64, ARM64, Power 8, including those that require all loads and stores to be naturally aligned. The basic strategy is to perform single-byte moves until the source pointer is 8-byte aligned. From that point on, the source data is always loaded in aligned 8-byte chunks, while the destination is written in the minimal number of chunks needed under the requirement that each chunk needs to be written in naturally-aligned fashion (2<sup>n</sup>-byte objects are accessed on 2<sup>n</sup>-byte boundaries).

Note that reading in 8-byte chunks may read bytes beyond the allocated memory of the source string. This is harmless if the loads are aligned, because they will never cross a page boundary and therefore never touch memory that belongs to a different process. Therefore, this is allowed under C's "as-if" rule, that is, no deviation from abstract machine semantics is observed. However, memory checker tools usually do complain about this, because the access is out of bounds relative to the allocated object.

As each 8-byte chunk of the source string is loaded, a quick check is performed to see if it contains a zero byte indicating the end of the string. If that is the case, the last chunk is written out byte-wise until the end of the source string is reached. The quick check for a null-byte uses a technique [posted to the newsgroup](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.c/2HtQXvg7iKc/xOJeipH6KLMJ) `comp.lang.c` on April 8, 1987 by Alan Mycroft. He defined the following for detecting a null byte in a 32-bit word, which is trivially extendable to 64-bit operands.

```
#define has_nullbyte_(x) ((x - 0x01010101) & ~x & 0x80808080)
```

The code below is written for reasonable clarity and is not fully optimized. In particular there are still loops for the byte-wise handling of the end cases which could be unrolled. In real life applications, the strings passed to `strcpy()` are often surprisingly short, so handling the end cases at the highest possible speed is often essential. The code uses a number of helper functions, and relies on compiler optimizations to inline these, so it should be compiled at a high optimization level.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define M0 0x0101010101010101ULL // Mycroft's first mask (LSBs)
#define M1 0x8080808080808080ULL // Mycroft's second mask (MSBs)
#define BM 0x00000000000000ffULL // mask for byte
#define HM 0x000000000000ffffULL // mask for half-word
#define WM 0x00000000ffffffffULL // mask for word

#define HAS_NULLBYTE(x) (((x) - M0) & ~(x) & M1)

void store_byte (uintptr_t a, uint8_t b)
{
    *((uint8_t *)(void *)a) = b;
}

void store_half (uintptr_t a, uint16_t b)
{
    assert ((a & 1) == 0);
    *((uint16_t *)(void *)a) = b;
}

void store_word (uintptr_t a, uint32_t b)
{
    assert ((a & 3) == 0);
    *((uint32_t *)(void *)a) = b;
}

void store_dword (uintptr_t a, uint64_t b)
{
    assert ((a & 7) == 0);
    *((uint64_t *)(void *)a) = b;
}

uint8_t load_byte (uintptr_t a)
{
    return *((uint8_t *)(void *)a);
}

uint64_t load_dword (uintptr_t a)
{
    assert ((a & 7) == 0);
    return *((uint64_t *)(void *)a);
}

void store_last_dword (uintptr_t d, uint64_t t)
{
    uint8_t b;
    do {
        b = t & 0xff;
        store_byte (d, b);
        d++;
        t = t >> 8;
    } while (b);
}

void store_8 (uintptr_t d, uintptr_t diff)
{   
    uint64_t t, zero_byte;
    do {
        t = load_dword (d + diff);
        zero_byte = HAS_NULLBYTE (t);
        d += 8;
        if (!zero_byte) {
            store_dword (d - 8, t);
        }
    } while (!zero_byte);
    store_last_dword (d - 8, t);
}

void store_44 (uintptr_t d, uintptr_t diff)
{
    uint64_t t, zero_byte;
    do {
        t = load_dword (d + diff);
        zero_byte = HAS_NULLBYTE (t);
        d += 8;
        if (!zero_byte) {
            store_word (d - 8, (uint32_t)(t >>  0) & WM);
            store_word (d - 4, (uint32_t)(t >> 32) & WM); 
        }
    } while (!zero_byte);
    store_last_dword (d - 8, t);
}

void store_242 (uintptr_t d, uintptr_t diff)
{
    uint64_t t, zero_byte;
    do {
        t = load_dword (d + diff);
        zero_byte = HAS_NULLBYTE (t);
        d += 8;
        if (!zero_byte) {
            store_half (d - 8, (uint16_t)((t >>  0) & HM));
            store_word (d - 6, (uint32_t)((t >> 16) & WM));
            store_half (d - 2, (uint16_t)((t >> 48) & HM));
        }
    } while (!zero_byte);
    store_last_dword (d - 8, t);
}

void store_1421 (uintptr_t d, uintptr_t diff)
{
    uint64_t t, zero_byte;
    do {
        t = load_dword (d + diff);
        zero_byte = HAS_NULLBYTE (t);
        d += 8;
        if (!zero_byte) {
            store_byte (d - 8, (uint8_t )((t >>  0) & BM));
            store_word (d - 7, (uint32_t)((t >>  8) & WM));
            store_half (d - 3, (uint16_t)((t >> 40) & HM));
            store_byte (d - 1, (uint8_t )((t >> 56) & BM));
        }
    } while (!zero_byte);
    store_last_dword (d - 8, t);
}

void store_1241 (uintptr_t d, uintptr_t diff)
{
    uint64_t t, zero_byte;
    do {
        t = load_dword (d + diff);
        zero_byte = HAS_NULLBYTE (t);
        d += 8;
        if (!zero_byte) {
            store_byte (d - 8, (uint8_t )((t >>  0) & BM));
            store_half (d - 7, (uint16_t)((t >>  8) & HM));
            store_word (d - 5, (uint32_t)((t >> 24) & WM));
            store_byte (d - 1, (uint8_t )((t >> 56) & BM));
        }
    } while (!zero_byte);
    store_last_dword (d - 8, t);
}

char* my_strcpy (char *dst, const char* src)
{
    uintptr_t s = (uintptr_t)(void *)src;
    uintptr_t d = (uintptr_t)(void *)dst;
    uintptr_t diff = s - d;
    uint8_t b = 0xff;

    // align source pointer to next 8-byte boundary
    int unaligned_bytes = (s & 7) ? (8 - (s & 7)) : 0;
    while (unaligned_bytes && (b != 0)) {
        b = load_byte (d + diff);
        store_byte (d, b);
        d++;
        unaligned_bytes--;
    }

    // source now 8-byte aligned, write destination according to its alignment
    if (b) {
        switch (d & 7) {
        case 0: store_8    (d, diff);
            break;
        case 1: store_1241 (d, diff);
            break;
        case 2: store_242  (d, diff);
            break;
        case 3: store_1421 (d, diff);
            break;
        case 4: store_44   (d, diff);
            break;
        case 5: store_1241 (d, diff);
            break;
        case 6: store_242  (d, diff);
            break;
        case 7: store_1421 (d, diff);
            break;
        }
    }
    return dst;
}

int main (void)
{
    const char a[] = "0123456789 the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
    char* src =  malloc (sizeof(a));
    int buffer_len = sizeof(a) + 16;
    char* res =  malloc (buffer_len); 
    char* ref =  malloc (buffer_len);

    printf ("src=%p  res=%p  ref=%p\n", a, res, ref);

    for (int srcofs = 0; srcofs < 8; srcofs++) {
        for (int dstofs = 0; dstofs < 8; dstofs++) {
            for (size_t len = 0; len < sizeof(a); len++) {
                 memcpy (src, a, sizeof(a));
                 src[len] = 0;
                 memset (res, 0xff, buffer_len);
                 memset (ref, 0xff, buffer_len);
                 my_strcpy (res + dstofs, src + srcofs);
                 strcpy    (ref + dstofs, src + srcofs);
                 if (memcmp (res, ref, buffer_len) != 0) {
                     printf ("error @ srcofs=%d  dstofs=%d  len=%llu\n", 
                             dstofs, srcofs, len);
                 }
            }
        }
    }
    printf ("Test passed\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been in a similar situation before where I've needed to copy large chunks of data with a bit-flip (so I couldn't just use memcpy()). The basic plan is to copy eight-byte chunks as far as possible and then mop up any odd bytes at the end. But we have to be careful if either of the source or destination are not eight-byte aligned. This is a simplified version, the handling of non-aligned data could be improved.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

// Try to copy a string 8 bytes at a time
void myStrcpy(char *dest, const char *src) {
    size_t n = 1 + strlen(src);

    // Check we're aligned
    if ((((uintptr_t) dest) % 8) || (((uintptr_t) src) % 8)) {
        strcpy(dest, src);
        return;
    }

    // Copy eight-byte chunks as far as possible
    const uint64_t *s = (uint64_t *) src;
    uint64_t *d = (uint64_t *) dest;
    for(; n >= 8; n -= 8) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Long copy\n");
        *d++ = *s++;
    }

    // Now mop up any remaining bytes
    src = (const char *) s;
    dest = (char *) d;
    while(n-- > 0) {
        *dest++ = *src++;
        fprintf(stderr, "Short copy\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    char s[] ="3r78cfjkcu8cdecowfcjefj0fj6d4j0e89j6rgffjk34kk4kik3f--f?";
    char d[sizeof s];

    myStrcpy(d, s);
    puts(s);
    puts(d);
}
```

John